# How to create an anonymous function that returns `True`?

Tags: python, python-2.7, lambda

I have some code which only runs if a specific hardware device is attached. While debugging I want to forgo this restriction.

I attempt to do this by temporarily replacing the function that checks if the hardware is attached, with an anonymous function that simply returns `True`:

```
import drm

def OnStartButton(self, evt):
    # Don't check for dongle in debug mode.
    if Globals.DEBUG:
        # Store the original function so we can reassign it later.
        func_store = drm.is_dongle_attached
        drm.is_dongle_attached = lambda x: return True
    if drm.is_dongle_attached():
        do_some_stuff()
    if Globals.DEBUG:
        # Reassign function back to the original.
        drm.is_dongle_attached = func_store
```

However, this doesn't seem to be a legal construct, as I get a `SyntaxError` on line:

```
drm.is_dongle_attached = lambda x: return True
                                        ^
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use `return` statements in `lambda` functions. In fact, you can only use expressions in it. So, simply do

```
lambda x: True
```

Quoting [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#lambda),

> functions created with lambda expressions cannot contain statements.

---

Actually in your case, you are calling `is_dongle_attached` without any parameters. So, you need to define the `lambda` function without an argument, like this

```
drm.is_dongle_attached = lambda: True
```

Answer (score 0):

Also,

```
drm.is_dongle_attached := func_store
```

to

```
drm.is_dongle_attached = func_store
```